# Resistance and saving throws

Tags: dnd-5e, saving-throw, damage-resistance

If i have resistance against a damage type and if i get a success on that damage types saving throw, does the damage halved twice? I checked the players handbooks for this but i couldn't find any spesific explanation

Comment: Welcome to the site! This question already has an answer, so I linked it to the current one to make sure we don't get the same answers copied to multiple places. If the linked question doesn't fully answer your question, feel free to edit this one to explain what's missing.